# what's wrong with this HQL query?

Tags: hibernate, grails, groovy, hql

I'm executing the following HQL query in my Grails app:

```
def maxIndex = VirtualSubOrder.find(
    'select max(vso.index) from VirtualSubOrder vso where vso.virtualOrder = ?', 
    [virtualOrder])
```

The `VirtualSubOrder` class definitely has an (Integer) `index` property and a `virtualOrder` property.

When I try to execute the query above I get the error:

> org.codehaus.groovy.grails.orm.hibernate.exceptions.GrailsQueryException: Invalid query [select max(vso.index) from VirtualSubOrder vso where vso.virtualOrder = ?] for domain class [class com.example.VirtualSubOrder]

Comment: Is there something wrong with this HQL query?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I believe you want to use `VirtualSubOrder.executeQuery()` instead of `find()`.  `find` is for returning domain instances and `executeQuery` is for arbitrary HQL.