# Invalid query on a HQL join query with proper syntax

Tags: hibernate, grails, grails-orm

I have a HQL join query as below

```
SELECT first FROM FirstTable AS first, SecondTable AS second WHERE second.firstTable = first;
```

This above query returns as Invalid query. But if I use the same above query without the `SELECT first` it works perfectly fine. I am using the proper syntax as in the documentation. Any idea on what might be the mistake which I am missing or any fix? And I am using the Grails Dynamic finders to run the HQL i.e.,

```
FirstTable.findAll(hql.toString(),params)
```

Where `hql` is a string builder which I am usign to build the query with all the required parameters(`param`).

The complete error which I get is as below

> org.codehaus.groovy.grails.orm.hibernate.exceptions.GrailsQueryException: Invalid query [SELECT first FROM FirstTable AS first, SecondTable AS second WHERE second.firstTable = first group by first.id order by first.id] for domain class [class com.model.FirstTable]

`FirstTable` has a `OneToMany` mapping to `SecondTable` and `Secondtable` has a `OneToOne` mapping to `FirstTable`

Comment: Try removing the as first. Write only FirstTable first. Same thing with second

Comment: @XavierBouclet I don't think that should make a difference. Anyhow, I did try that already it still has the same error.

Comment: Try with the id something like second.firstTable.id = first.id. Could you add your mappings for FirstTable and SecondTable?

Comment: Have you tried changing it to SELECT second.firstTable?

Comment: @RobObdeijn Yes I have and still the same error.

Comment: @XavierBouclet I have added the mappings. And I did try your suggestion, still the same error.

Comment: I don't see any mapping in this post.

Comment: If I look at the documentation for the findAll method it seems that it is not intended for use with a SELECT clause. Is there any particular reason you'd want this?

Comment: `SELECT new map(first as first) FROM FirstTable first, SecondTable  second WHERE second.firstTable = first;` how is that ? I suspect you have more than 1 record and therefore it is breaking you could try `select count(first) as count FROM FirstTable first, SecondTable  second WHERE second.firstTable = first;`

Answer (score 1):

Like you said, it works when you remove SELECT first. Because findAll method is only responsible for queries like "from FirstTable".
It is recommended to use executeQuery instead.

In your case it would be something like :

```
FirstTable.executeQuery("from FirstTable AS first, SecondTable AS second WHERE second.firstTable = first");
```

See these links for more detail : [issues1428](https://github.com/grails/grails-core/issues/1428) or [duplicate so](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13747950/whats-wrong-with-this-hql-query)

Answer (score -1):

You are trying to select whole table as a column, maybe you should try following :

```
  SELECT * FROM FirstTable AS first, SecondTable AS second WHERE second.firstTable = first;
```

Comment: It still gives the same error and I don't think using `*` is something allowed in HQL when doing joins. we will have to specify the table's alias which we need to display.